# How would I go about creating a tear drop shape of cubes in mathematica?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I am just practicing making some new designs with Mathematica and I thought of this recently.  I want to make a tear drop shape (doesn't matter the orientation) constructed of mini cubes.  I am familiar with the preliminary material, I am just having some difficulty getting it to work.

Comment: Why not post some pictures to  display the result which you want?

Comment: You should leave the question up and not edit it out. (Please. :)

Comment: I want to make some socially sharp graffiti à la Banksy. I am familiar with the preliminary material, just having some difficulty getting it to work.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 8):

My interpretation of the posed question and a quick solution for it based on the teardrop shape from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TeardropCurve.html

```
m=3
Array[With[{
u=RandomReal[{0,2\[Pi]}],
t=Mod[(1-Abs[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.1,.3]]])\[Pi],\[Pi]]
},
{Sin[t]Sin[t/2]^m Cos[u],Sin[t]Sin[t/2]^m Sin[u],Cos[t]}]&,
250];
pts=Join[Mean/@RandomChoice[%,{300,2}],%];
cubes=Cube[#,.04]&/@%;
Graphics3D[cubes,ImageSize->Large]
```

where `m` controls the shape of the drop. This code results in:

[image: Drop]

This implementation allows for overlapping cubes and the distribution is not necessarily ideal but it is simple. If one only wants the surface filled, one can drop the mean points using `pts=%;` in the code above. Experimenting with different `m`, more or less points and formatting styles/options for the cubes/Graphics3D might result in a more pleasing graphics.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @N0va provide the tear drop surface. Here we draw by another approach.

```
Clear["`*"];
m = 3;
surf = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Sin[t/2]^m Cos[u], 
    Sin[t] Sin[t/2]^m Sin[u], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, {u, 0, π}];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[surf];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Yellow], 
  Cube[#, .025] & /@ RandomPoint[reg, 2000]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

I don't know how to use the `VertexColors` to all the cube.

```
Clear["`*"];
m = 3;
surf = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Sin[t/2]^m Cos[u], 
    Sin[t] Sin[t/2]^m Sin[u], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {u, 0, \[Pi]}];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[surf];
points = RandomPoint[reg, 2000];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[0.5], 
  Riffle[Hue[#] & /@ Rescale[Last /@ points], 
   Cube[#, .025] & /@ points]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]